# Weak convergence using convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, uniform-distribution

**QUESTION:** Let
$$
    g_n(x) =\begin{cases}
    1-\cos(2n\pi x) &  \mbox{if} \; 0\leq x \leq 1 \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}\\
    \end{cases}
$$
be the density function of $G_n$. (I've already checked that it is indeed a density function).
However, I'm struggling to show that $G_n$ converges weakly to the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and also to show that its densities $g_n$ do not converge.

**MY ATTEMPT:** The hint is to use convergence in distribution (by definition). So, I've tried to use Taylor's series, otherwise, I'm not sure whether this is the right way... I guess I'm not providing a precise proof. In addition I don't know how to show that the sequence $g_n$ doesn't converge.

**COMMENT:** I did not understand why the downvote? Is there something that someone can suggest as a improvement? So than, I'll edit.

Comment: Have you found the CDF of $G_n$?

Comment: Not yet, so this is the first step? I'll do right now...

Comment: Yes. What did you have in mind for "The hint is to use convergence in distribution (by definition)"?

Comment: The definition of convergence in distribution is $G=\lim_{n\to \infty} G_n$ (weak limit). So, with your suggestion, first I have to calculate CDF, after I have to take the limit going to infinity...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \in (-\infty, 0]$, then $$G_n(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} g_n(y) \ \mathrm{d} y= 0$$

And if $x \in [0, 1]$, it's clear that $$G_n(x) = x - \frac{\sin(2\pi n x)}{2 \pi n}$$

Finally if $x > 1$ it's also easy to see that $G_n(x) = 1$. Putting it all together it's clear that $G_n(x) \to G(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, where $G$ is the cumulative distribution function of a continuous uniform random variable with parameters $0$ and $1$.